# WebStorm: Ignore files in project without removing from source control?

Tags: webstorm

I have a large project with some files I don't generally need to work with.  I frequently use the CTRL+SHIFT+F to find strings across all files in the project. There are files I would like to exclude from this search.  I found [this in the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-project-structure.html#exclude-files):

> If you don't need a file right now but you don't want to completely
>   remove it, you can temporarily exclude the file from the project.
>   Excluded files are ignored by code completion, navigation, and
>   inspections.
>
> > To exclude a file, right-click it in the Project tool window and select Mark as Plain Text from the menu. The file is marked with the
> >     plain text icon icon in the directory tree.
> >
> > To revert the changes, right-click the file and select Mark as  from the menu.

First off, this seems odd... "Mark as plain text"?  Regardless, I tried it and the files still show up in search.  Is there anything else I can do to essentially "ignore" the files without removing them from source control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text files (marked as plain text, as well as usual `.txt` files) are not excluded from search - only from navigation/completion.
To exclude file from all indexes, you can add it to **Exclude files:** list in **Settings | Directories**. See [your link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-project-structure.html#exclude-files), **Excluding files and folders by name patterns** section

Note that folders can be excluded using **Mark directory as/Excluded** right-click menu item. There is no such option for individual files unfortunately. If you miss it, please vote for [IDEA-139359](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139359)

Comment: I saw that, I guess I should have mentioned it, but since I want to exclude a lot of very specific files (ie, not all JS files) I would have to type each full filename individually.  I was hoping for a "right-click" solution similar to the Plain Text method.  I guess I'll just have to deal with it, thanks though.

Comment: Ahh, now your edit might be useful in most of my cases. I would still like a "exclude" option at a file level though.  Thanks!